# Test on each Authorization endpoints?

Tags: design-patterns, testing, dry

I'm writing an API server. The framework we're using is Rails + Pundit + graphql-ruby, but I guess this question is framework-independent.

We have authentication + authorization implemented on the resources on each different endpoints; and we want to make sure that the endpoint which requires login, are properly protected (i.e., you actually have to be a valid user in order to access the endpoint).

In order to do that, the only approach I can come up with is that... to mock an anonymous access onto each of the different endpoints we're having. However, I think this is not DRY - the code for checking these endpoints are basically the same.

(Currently there're mostly authentication, but we'll probably put in more authorization on the endpoint level.)

Is there any better way of doing this? Specifically, how to ensure endpoints are securely with authentication rule enforced, while maintaining DRY test cases?

---

PS: this question is mainly asking for opinion on how to design the test cases. It was first asked in the [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189409/test-on-each-authorization-endpoints) and [main site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240621/test-on-each-authorization-endpoints/49241879#49241879), but marked as off-topic since it doesn't include any code.

So I'm asking here in the StackOverFlow main site instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry about DRY in test cases. Instead, focus on ensuring that each test case is explicit about testing specific behavior in your application.

Although it is primarily about unit tests, [this question on Stack Overflow about "DAMP not DRY"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6453235/572) is relevant to all types of tests. By not having DRY tests, I believe the intended behavior of the system will be easier to understand by using the tests as a form of documentation - you'll easily be able to find out if a particular endpoint requires authentication or not and focus on testing any authorization aspects. If either the need for authentication changes or authorization rules around a particular endpoint change, having this repeated code will make it much easier to change the test cases around that particular endpoint - only if global changes are made will large numbers of test cases need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. Depending on your design you can have two options:
- if your logic is centalized, e.g. encapsulated in auth module then you need to test only this module
- if you embedded authentication/authorization logic into controllers then you need to test all of them

Despite design you need to test different scenarios, like:
- anonymous user 
- incorrect credentials
- incorrect role rights

The more you conver different scenarios the more you can be sure that your authentication/authorization layer works correctly.